# Problem with "Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following" by Suzuki Abe

Tags: computer-vision, algorithms, opencv

I have a Problem with the Paper "Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following" by Suzuki and Abe.
In the Chapter "Appendix I: The Formal Description of Algorithm 1" I think I found an issue:

Consider this input image:

[image: Binary structure of the image]

We start by finding the first not zero pixel and decide that it is a start point for an outer border. If we follow the algorithm in the paper, it looks like this after the detection of the outer border.

[image]

But if it looks like this one, we will never found the hole border, because the hole border starting point is found when the value $f$ of pixel $(i,j)$ is higher than 1, and the value of pixel $(i,j+1)$ is 0.

In my opinion the step (3.3) is wrong, if you compare the algorithm to the pictures in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Your output has a mistake, since it's giving `-2` to left pixels. Let's add some coordinates to your image:

[image: Original image]

You start in raster scan order and hit step (1)(a): it's an outer border, so $NBD\leftarrow2$, $(i,j)\leftarrow(1,1)$, $(i_2,j_2)\leftarrow(1,0)$.
Let's call $P_{start}\equiv(i,j)$, and $P_{from}\equiv(i_2,j_2)$.

Then you move to step (2) and set its parent to 1.

Now the **counterclockwise** border following algorithm:

(3.1 aka `InitPhase`): search *clockwise* around $P_{start}$ starting from $P_{from}$ a nonzero pixel. You check in order: $(1,0)$, $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$, and eventually you find $(1,2)$. Now you set $(i_1,j_1)\leftarrow(1,2)$. Let's call $P_{start\mbox{-}from}\equiv(i_1,j_1)$. In our case we have the following result:

[image: Original image with start and start-from]

$P_{start}$ is yellow and $P_{start\mbox{-}from}$ is green. You need the starting point and the original direction to detect multiple passes through it, and avoid stopping too early.

(3.2 aka `Setup`): $(i_2,j_2)\leftarrow(1,2)$ and $(i_3,j_3)\leftarrow(1,1)$. Let's call $P_{cur}\equiv(i_3,j_3)$ and $P_{prev}\equiv(i_2,j_2)$.

(3.3 aka `FindNext`): search *counterclockwise* around $P_{cur}$ starting from the next of $P_{prev}$ a nonzero pixel. You check in order: $(0,2)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, and eventually you find $(2,1)$. Now you set $(i_4,j_4)\leftarrow(2,1)$. Let's call $P_{next}\equiv(i_4,j_4)$. In our case we have the following result:

[image]

$P_{prev}$ is pink, $P_{cur}$ is green, and $P_{next}$ is blue.

(3.4 aka `SetValue`): the image at $(i_3,j_3+1)=(1,2)$, the pixel to the right of $P_{cur}$, and at $P_{cur}$ is nonzero, so we are in case (b): $f(P_{cur})\leftarrow2$.

(3.5 aka `MoveNext`): $P_{prev} \leftarrow P_{cur}$ and $P_{cur} \leftarrow P_{next}$.

---

## Let's do it again!

(3.3 aka `FindNext`): search *counterclockwise* around $P_{cur}$ starting from the next of $P_{prev}$ a nonzero pixel. You check in order: $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(3,0)$ and eventually $P_{next}\leftarrow(3,1)$. We have the following result:

[image: Move next]

**Watch out: here is the trick**

(3.4 aka `SetValue`): the image at $(i_3,j_3+1)=(2,2)$, the pixel to the right of $P_{cur}$, is not a 0-pixels **examined in the substep (3.3)**. In fact we examined $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(3,0)$. So we are again in case (b): $f(P_{cur})\leftarrow2$.

Now you can keep going. The final result (before resuming the raster scan) will be:

[image: Result]

Wow. This was so long to explain...

Here is the specific point in the article:
[image]

Comment: Thx for the long explanation, but i still have some problems with the second round.
The case b is: "if the pixel (i3,j3+1) is not a 0-pixel" In our case i3, j3+1 is an zero pixel. So we should go with case a. I found another explanation on a website. There was the definition of case a a bit different. They add a small thing; The 0-Pixel has to belong to the higher tropoloigcal area. 
Then you dont have the problem that it has a negative number and you will find the hole boarder.

Comment: @Vanior: you didn't read case (b) completely. Check the edited version of the answer.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding comes from the wording, (3.4)(b) should read as follows:
If the pixel (i3, j3 + 1) was not examined in the substep (3.3) and fi3,j3 = 1, then fi3,j3 <- NBD.  The main confusion comes from the 0-pixel part and many implementations I have seen online check if that pixel is 0 (but this thinking is wrong, that pixel is undefined as it was not examined).